# pandas load dataframe from string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to crawl SEC Edgar 13F form (txt format) and parse it into `pandas.DataFrame`,

original data link: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000119312512060928/0001193125-12-060928.txt

I try to use bs4 to extract table like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page(url):
    url_client = urlopen(url)
    page = url_client.read()
    url_client.close()
    return page

history_url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000119312513060317/0001193125-13-060317.txt'

txt_soup = BeautifulSoup(getPage(history_url), 'xml')
```

then I extract table from soup :

```
table = txt_soup.find_all('TABLE')[0]
table_header = table.contents[1].contents[0]
table_data = table.contents[1].contents[1]
```

The `table_data` looks like this:

```
<S> <C> <C> <C> <C> <C> <C> <C> <C> <C>
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      112,209     1,952,142 Shared-Defined 4           1,952,142       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      990,116    17,225,400 Shared-Defined 4, 5       17,225,400       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109       48,274       839,832 Shared-Defined 4, 7          839,832       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      111,689     1,943,100 Shared-Defined 4, 8, 11    1,943,100       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      459,532     7,994,634 Shared-Defined 4, 10       7,994,634       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109    6,912,308   120,255,879 Shared-Defined 4, 11     120,255,879       -        -
AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109       80,456     1,399,713 Shared-Defined 4, 13       1,399,713       -        -
ARCHER DANIELS
  MIDLAND CO        COM           039483102      163,151     5,956,600 Shared-Defined 4, 5        5,956,600       -        -
```

Now I want to convert this str into `pandas.DataFrame`, I tried using :

```
from io import StringIO
pd.read_csv(StringIO(table_data.text), header=None)
```

This above code failed, and returns error :

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

How can I parse this kind of txt table correctly? Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced in Pandas Dataframes, but by looking at the code I believe I know what the issue is.

On line 3:

```
EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      112,209     1,952,142 Shared-Defined 4           1,952,142       -        -
```

It appears to be splitting the data by commas (as csv files usually use a comma delimiter).
 So instead of passing one field your passing six:

```
EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      112
209     1
952
142 Shared-Defined 4           1
952
142       -        -
```

My suggested solution would be to remove all commas from table_data:

```
table_data = table_data.replace(',', '')
```

And try it again. Please let me know how this goes!

Comment: Thanks Brice, there are some comma in columns' data, such as the second row : `AMERICAN
  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      990,116    17,225,400 Shared-Defined 4, 5       17,225,400       -        -`